# ¿Cómo cambiar el mensaje de un commit?

Tags: git, git-commit

Acabo de hacer un commit:

```
git commit -m "este es un comentario"
```

Sin embargo, de repente me he dado cuenta de que este mensaje no es el correcto. ¿Puedo modificarlo? Si sí, ¿cómo?

Si vuelvo a escribir `git commit -m "un nuevo comentario"` hará otro commit en lugar de modificar el que ya hice.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/179123/1983854

Answer (score 39, accepted):

La opción más práctica y rápida es usar:

```
git commit --amend
```

Tras lo cual se te abrirá el editor para que puedas modificar el mensaje.

Si quieres escribir algo totalmente nuevo, puedes decir directamente:

```
git commit --amend -m "Este es el nuevo comentario"
```

Puedes ver más detalles en la respuesta en la versión inglesa a [Edit an incorrect commit message in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/179147/1983854).

Answer (score 5):

También puedes editar el histórico de commits para modificar mas de un mensaje, usando git rebase

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

Esto te abrira un editor de texto (vim) donde puedes actualizar los mensajes del histórico de commits.

Comment: En realidad, ahí no se modifican directamente los mensajes, para hacerlos hay que cambiar la acción por "reword" lo cual después permite modificar el mensaje.

Comment: Correcto, gracias por la aclaración ahora actualizo la respuesta.