# ¿Cómo corregir el mensaje del último commit?

Tags: mercurial, control-de-versiones

Hice commit a mi último cambio usando Mercurial, sin embargo, necesito cambiar el mensaje de ese commit para evitar confusiones a los otros programadores en otros branches.

Existe el comando `rollback` pero no necesito realmente deshacer todo, solo quiero editar el mensaje.

¿Existe alguna forma de corregir ese mensaje?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La respuesta de @fedorqui es correcta, se debe usar `--amend` para corregir el commit, pero antes se deben tener en cuenta algunas cosas para futuras referencias del problema.

### [Fases en Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases)

En general, las fases son usadas en Mercurial para prevenir reescrituras accidentales en los changesets.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según se aprecia en el cuadro, solo en la fase `public` un changeset o commit es inmutable.

### ¿Cuándo se vuelve un commit inmutable?

> Cada changeset que se le hace push o pull desde o hacia un servidor público es puesto en la fase `public`.

Debido a que yo ya había hecho un `push` hacia mi repositorio en BitBucket, mi commit se había vuelto inmutable y no pude aplicarle `--amend`:

```
$ hg commit --amend
abort: cannot amend public changesets
```

### Solución

Si no se ha hecho el push al commit, `--amend` abrirá un editor para cambiar el mensaje:

```
Mensaje corregido


HG: Enter commit message.  Lines beginning with 'HG:' are removed.
HG: Leave message empty to abort commit.
HG: --
HG: user: César Bustíos <cesarbustios@gmail.com>
HG: branch 'default'
HG: added test.txt
```

Si por el contrario ya se ha hecho el push, es posible usar el comando `phase` para forzar el cambio de la fase de `public` a `draft`:

```
$ hg phase --draft --force CHANGESET
$ hg commit --amend
```

Comment: ¡Buena investigación y respuesta!

Comment: Gracias! Me tomo tiempo, pero valio la pena ;-)

Comment: Por cierto, creo que tu respuesta debería ser la aceptada pues es la que contiene más información útil y la solución *definitiva*.

Comment: @fedorqui creo que tienes razón, ya está. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 5):

Al parecer desde [Mercurial 2.2](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WhatsNew#Mercurial_2.2_.282012-05-01.29) existe la opción `--amend`, al [igual que en `git`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/171/83):

```
hg commit --amend
```

Dice la [página de ayuda](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#commit):

> The `--amend` flag can be used to amend the parent of the working
>   directory with a new commit that contains the changes in the parent in
>   addition to those currently reported by `hg status`, if there are any.
>   The old commit is stored in a backup bundle in `.hg/strip-backup`.

Esto es:

> La opción `--amend` se puede usar para corregir el directorio superior
>   al que se está con un nuevo *commit* que contenga los cambios en el
>   directorio superior además de los que ya menciona `hg status`, si es
>   que hay alguno. El antiguo commit se guarda en `.hg/strip-backup`.

Comment: Entonces despues de mi ultimo commit solo tendría que hacer: `hg commit --amend -m "Mensaje editado"`?

Comment: Sí, al parecer sí. Desgraciadamente no tengo Mercurial instalado y no puedo probarlo. Haz uno de prueba y si funciona ya sabremos que es así.

Comment: Pues, recién puedo probar esto y al parecer no es tan fácil, depende de algunas cosas!

Answer (score 1):

Una forma bastante fácil es usar:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

Esto te abrirá un editor de texto con los últimos commits donde puedes editar los mensajes asociados, una vez realizado los cambios guardas y sales del editor.

Comment: Hola, la pregunta es para **Mercurial**, esto aplica?

Comment: Con la extension rebase https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension quizas

Comment: Hola este comando de GIT, me parece que para Mercurial no aplica.

Comment: @Elenasys si, me lo imaginaba :P

Comment: @Elenasys efectivamente, gracias por la corrección.